# Display a link inside an if-condition using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I display a `href` link inside an `if` condition using javascript?

Comment: I can display a simple text based on a user input. For an example if the user inputs "aaaa" I can display some text. But I couldn't display a link like that

Comment: Your question is little confusing. You need to display links based on user selection ?

Comment: yes. It's just for experimenting. I'm just learning things by following some tutorials :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("fname");
   if(x.value.indexOf("aaaa")>=0)document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= "<a href="+x.value+">"+ x.value + "</a>" ;
        else document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=x.value;
    }
    </script>

    <form method="post" action="esegui.php">
      Name<br><input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()"> 
    </form>

    <p id="result"></p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But how can I display the link only if the input = "aaaa"

Answer (score 0):

You can create anchor tag using JavaScript following way:

```
var aTag = document.createElement('a');
aTag.setAttribute('href',"http://www.google.com");
aTag.innerHTML = "aaa";
document.body.appendChild(aTag);
```

Put above code in if condition will create anchor tag(link).

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is a little bit confusing, I'll try to help you

If what you want is to create a specific link, do this:

```
var link = window.document.createElement("a");
var str = window.document.getElementById("theidofyourinput").value;
link.textContent = str;
link.href = 'http://www.linkofyourpage';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(link);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try researching the [createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) method in JavaScript, calling it to create an anchor element in the body of your `if` statement e.g.

```
var myLink = document.createElement('a');
myLink.appendChild(document.createTextNode('link name')); //visible text
myLink.setAttribute('href', 'http://google.com');         //link href attribute
document.getElementById('someId').appendChild(myLink);    //append the element
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to do this but you have not mentioned specific scenario so do like this:

In HTML:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

In Java script:

```
var markup = "<a href="www.stackoverflow.com">link</a>";

var v = document.getElementById("test") ;
v.innerHtml(v );
```